# Sample code to create Pivot table in open XML SDK

Tags: asp.net, excel, openxml-sdk, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table in excel using the open XML SDK from my .net web application. I have got an excel file, for which I have to generate a pivot table.

**Please provide any sample code.**

Answer (score 0):

I have some similar task.

Take a look at this [Power Tools for OpenXML](http://powertools.codeplex.com/).

It really helped me, although now I need to figure out how to initialize the pivot table with some structure.

PS. you might need to expose this from a webservice.